# How get all quantities locations visible

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have 3 locations for inventory location A,B,C

And the following code

```
<?php 

    if (count($cart) == 0) { ?>

    <tr>
        <td colspan='8'>
            <div class='warning_message' style='padding: 7px;'><?php echo $this->lang->line('sales_no_items_in_cart'); ?></div>
        </td>
    </tr>

<?php } else {

    foreach(array_reverse($cart, true) as $line=>$item) {

    echo form_open("sales/edit_item/$line");

?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo anchor("sales/delete_item/$line",'['.$this->lang->line('common_delete').']');?></td>
<td><?php echo $item['item_number']; ?></td>
<td style="align: center;"><?php echo $item['name']; ?><br /> [<?php echo $item['in_stock'] ?> in <?php echo $item['stock_name']; ?>]
<?php echo form_hidden('location', $item['item_location']); ?>
</td>
```

This works perfectly, but i will like to be able to view all location name with quantities at once.

The sistema works like this! first select location then item then it shows quantities based on locations, when switch location and search for the item again it show quantity of the new location, I will like soon as i select and item it output all location name and quantities in a text fields

And i will like it to provide all location info at once

[image]

Comment: Looks like you use CodeIgniter or something similar. Please tag your question with that. Also your code is not closing the `foreach` loop, nor the `else` block.

Comment: yes i am sorry it is codeigniter